# Bidirectional relationship between nodes in Boost.Spirit

Tags: boost-spirit

I'm using Boost.Spirit to parse structures similar to

```
namespace Foo { class Bar { ... } }
```

This works just fine: I get an object of type `namespace_declaration`, it has a list of variants for the things it contains, such as `class_declaration`s.

My question is this: how can I ensure that, at the parsing stage, the `class_declaration` can refer to its containing `namespace_declaration`? In other words, how can I refer to that object which is the context of what I've just parsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. At least not comfortably.

The fact that you wish for this is probably a sign that you are conflating parsing and processing code.

If all you need is a semantic check, you can try to inject the necessary details in the sub-rules for context, e.g. using inherited attributes.

This can not reasonably be "a bi-directional relationship" if only for the fact that the enclosing construct is (obviously) not even complete yet:

- In the case of `namespace X { class Y { }; }` logically you can expect the name `"X"` to have been parsed - but there's no guarantee that it has already been assigned into the exposed attribute value
- Idem for the condition expression in the case of `while (condition) { statement; }`
- But, consider `do { statement; } while (condition);` and you can see why you cannot expect `statement` to know about the enclosing control flow statement.

So, all in all, I would suggest

1. Separation of concerns: parse first, semantic checks, transformations, processing later
2. If you must have semantic information on the fly (e.g. because of contextual grammars) pass the context explicitly